# extend AuthenticatorBase in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, basic-authentication, form-authentication

I am trying to create a custom authenticator in Tomcat 7. 
So, my understanding is that I need to extend AuthenticatorBase class (similar to FormAuthenticator) and then mention the new authenticator's name in web.xml, something like this:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CUSTOMAUTH</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Create a Jar out of the Custom Authenticator class and put it in tomcatDir\lib\

Now where do I mention the mapping between "CUSTOMAUTH" and my class CustomAuthenticator.java which might be in , lets say, com.authentication.custom.CustomAuthenticator.java ?

Could you please let me know the path to the config file for both windows (my dev environment) as well as Linux (our actual servers).

Please correct me if I am wrong about any of the steps above.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: is it in server.xml?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override the method

`protected abstract String getAuthMethod();`

Here you must return CUSTOMAUTH